# Visual Studio native unit testing: Debug/console output?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Can anyone tell me how to enable or get debug or console text output when running unit tests in a native (C++) test project in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer should not include the phrase, "use Google Test".

Comment: Will switching subsystem to console help? (project properties/linker/system)

Comment: Nice idea but alas, no.  My code is outputting text using OutputDebugStringA and OutputDebugStringW.  I guess I need to use some other library?

Comment: I kind of solved it.  The debug output shows in the debug output window if you right-click and choose `debug' on whichever test in the test explorer window.  Otherwise it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debug output shows in the debug output window if you right-click and choose `debug' on whichever test in the test explorer window. Otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: Main Menu -> Test -> Windows -> Test Explorer, then right-click on one of the tests in the window to bring up its context menu and choose debug from there.

Comment: This seems to be true in VS 2017, using OutputDebugString(L"Message");

Answer (score 25):

In the unit test code, you can use

```
Logger::WriteMessage("My message string");
```

and the message will appear in the Output window.

Comment: Works okay if you have #include "CppUnitTest.h" and are in the context of a TEST_METHOD in a TEST_CLASS but not just anywhere.

Comment: Works if you add: "using Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::Logger" at the top

Answer (score 8):

Brian's answer is correct. Use

```
Logger::WriteMessage("some text");
```

and run the test normally (there is no need to debug). However, you also need to select "Tests" in the "Show output from" drop-down list at the top of the Output window.

[VS 2013 Output window with Tests output selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCUiQ.png)

Comment: The UI in Visual Studio 2019 remains the same: there's a "Tests" selection in the top of the "Output" window, and that's where the output will appear.